# Weka M5Rules encoding

Tags: weka

I am beginner with Weka data mining tool.

I am wondering how can I encode an output model of M5Rules into a C program that could be embedded in an energy consumption simulator. The complete model is described below.

A priori I would expect a kind of if-then-else encoding in C, but there are strange expressions in `IF` conditions of these rules, which I do not understand.

E.g., in `Rule: 1`, is this `IF` condition equivalent to `ExecTime <= 959678 && ExecTime > 767156`?

How do one interpret the conditions in `Rule: 15` and `Rule: 16` with respect to 849021 (are these two conditions equivalent)?

I will appreciate any help towards a possible C encoding of these rules :-).
Thanks a lot!

JH

************************ M5Rules output

```
Rule: 1
IF
    ExecTime <= 959678
    ExecTime <= 841942.5
    ExecTime > 767156
    ExecTime <= 797926.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.0474 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0444 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0353 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.1149 * _H08ZiN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 3.6692 * _H08aH99NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 0.0622 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0002 * ExecTime
    + 9283.9945 [905/5.48%]

Rule: 2
IF
    ExecTime <= 990800
    ExecTime > 841942.5
    ExecTime > 891748.5
    ExecTime <= 953522.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    5.7526 * _H08Y999NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0241 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 5.473 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 4.7454 * _H08aH99NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 0.0244 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0002 * ExecTime
    + 9962.3473 [1076/7.136%]

Rule: 3
IF
    ExecTime <= 922644.5
    ExecTime > 841942.5
    ExecTime <= 875547
    ExecTime <= 869750.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.0538 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0522 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.2158 * _H08ZiN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 3.025 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0858 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 4.3856 * _H08Yud9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0001 * ExecTime
    + 9675.1495 [890/5.322%]

Rule: 4
IF
    ExecTime > 922644.5
    ExecTime <= 1144991.5
    ExecTime <= 1100913.5
    ExecTime > 990800
    ExecTime > 1023515
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.0177 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0212 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0141 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.2791 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.1004 * _H08ZAt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.2871 * _H08ZvN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0029 * ExecTime
    + 7616.5061 [759/5.317%]

Rule: 5
IF
    ExecTime > 922644.5
    ExecTime <= 1175937.5
    ExecTime > 1061802
    ExecTime > 1112381.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.1694 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.03 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0678 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0004 * ExecTime
    + 10581.9568 [495/4.516%]

Rule: 6
IF
    ExecTime <= 922644.5
    ExecTime <= 768103.5
    ExecTime > 721726.5
    ExecTime <= 729278
    ExecTime > 722094
    ExecTime <= 724494
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.4341 * _H08Y999NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0958 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 11.1267 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 18.5669 * _H08ZiN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.2536 * _H08aH99NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 8.0408 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0942 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0121 * ExecTime
    + 17795.1451 [294/5.734%]

Rule: 7
IF
    ExecTime <= 990800
    ExecTime <= 869756.5
    ExecTime <= 768103.5
    ExecTime > 721636.5
    ExecTime <= 730227.5
    ExecTime <= 728964
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.1634 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.3896 * _H08Y999NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.1997 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.1235 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.3961 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.1817 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.2828 * _H08Yud9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.4399 * _H08ZAt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0003 * ExecTime
    + 8867.5503 [402/4.404%]

Rule: 8
IF
    ExecTime > 1061802
    ExecTime <= 1266307
    ExecTime > 1144257
    ExecTime > 1193767.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    -0.3281 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.062 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 13.1349 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0428 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 0.254 * _H08Yud9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.3602 * _H08ZAt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0028 * ExecTime
    + 8065.2375 [293/4.695%]

Rule: 9
IF
    ExecTime > 1061802
    ExecTime <= 1230073
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.117 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0723 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0625 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 17.6704 * _H08ZvN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0051 * ExecTime
    + 5341.2406 [283/7.376%]

Rule: 10
IF
    ExecTime > 1145764
    ExecTime > 1349259.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.1985 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.12 * _H08Yxt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.1002 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.005 * ExecTime
    + 5325.0455 [281/6.55%]

Rule: 11
IF
    ExecTime <= 922644.5
    ExecTime > 869756.5
    ExecTime > 881525
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.151 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.2828 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.6376 * _H08ZiN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0385 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0006 * ExecTime
    + 9300.7835 [253/4.516%]

Rule: 12
IF
    ExecTime <= 917420.5
    ExecTime > 768103.5
    ExecTime <= 869756.5
    ExecTime > 806810.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.1013 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.8919 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0522 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 0.0555 * _H08ZAt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0005 * ExecTime
    + 9049.7419 [228/4.466%]

Rule: 13
IF
    ExecTime <= 917420.5
    ExecTime > 768103.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.1663 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.3315 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0572 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0723 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.0782 * _H08ZAt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0047 * ExecTime
    + 5620.2818 [696/9.48%]

Rule: 14
IF
    ExecTime <= 1145764
    ExecTime > 845905
    ExecTime <= 959678
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    -0.5334 * _H08Y999NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.4001 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.7092 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.3418 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0004 * ExecTime
    + 9771.3597 [269/4.341%]

Rule: 15
IF
    ExecTime > 849021
    ExecTime > 1145764
    ExecTime > 1276509
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.9858 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.7268 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.3091 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.0006 * ExecTime
    + 10999.3844 [193/4.635%]

Rule: 16
IF
    ExecTime > 849021
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    0.682 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 15.4759 * _H08ZiN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.4643 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.6401 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 17.6902 * _H08Yud9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 15.1697 * _H08ZvN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.005 * ExecTime
    + 5395.084 [268/9.01%]

Rule: 17
IF
    ExecTime > 657837
    ExecTime <= 730227.5
THEN

EnergyTotal =
    1.749 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 1.5395 * _H08aFt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.686 * _H08aH99NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    - 1.0553 * _H08ZRt9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 22.5421 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 0.6172 * _H08Yud9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.y
    + 0.0005 * ExecTime
    + 8690.2253 [161/37.564%]

Rule: 18

EnergyTotal =
    12.3579 * _H08Y299NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 16.0776 * _H08aMd9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    - 10.38 * _H08ZvN9NEeOETou3oNmhPQ.x
    + 0.005 * ExecTime
    + 5484.0874 [252/25.693%]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule 1 is equivalent to ExecTime <= 797926.5 && ExecTime > 767156 (other conditions are spurious)
Rule 15 equals to ExecTime > 1276509
Rule 16 equals to ExecTime > 849021 (&& ExecTime <= 1276509)
(first rule that match wins)